# Can we add new filed inside elb access log?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, access-log

As of now i am getting ELB logs from S3. I want to add one more field inside the logs(elb access log). Is it possible to add new field when generating new access log?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do that?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly its not possible. Access logs have [fixed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html) format. If you require anything else that that, you have to produce custom logs from your application.

Comment: Thanks! How to create custom logs for load balancer? Give some suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

Access log format is fixed and you can't modify it.

The only thing that you can do is to put additional code in your application and when it loaded it can store additional details with custom log.